# Sequelize: How to make use of multiple operators to create a fetch of objects with an exclusion clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize 5 in a NodeJS/Express/Angular7 application using MySQL.

I have a table of images with a bidirectional hasMany relationship to a table of keywords through a join table.

I want to find all images that include keyword IDs in an array of IDs [**kewordsAnd**], excluding images that have keyword IDs in an array to exclude [**keywordsNot**].

The code right now is as follows:

```
Image.findAll({
  include: [ {
    model: Keywords,
    as: 'Keywords',
    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    where: {
      id: {
        [Op.and]: [
          { [Op.in]: keywordsAnd },
          { [Op.notIn]: keywordsNot }
        ]
      }
    }
  } ]
});
```

This correctly fetches all images that have IDs in the **keywordsAnd** array, but the **keywordsNot** array is completely ignored.

This is the generated SQL (line breaks added for readability)

```
const objectsAnd:  [ 430 ]
const objectsNot:  [ 779 ]
Executing (default): 

SELECT `image`.`id`, `image`.`status`, `image`.`image_type`, `image`.`embed`, 
`image`.`raw_path`, `image`.`thumb_path`, `image`.`detail_path`, `image`.`story_title`, 
`image`.`image_title`, `image`.`original_filename`, `image`.`description`, 
`image`.`geo_info`, `image`.`year_taken`, `image`.`credit_info`, 
`image`.`width`, `image`.`height`, `image`.`format`, `image`.`duration`, 
`image`.`created_at` 

AS `createdAt`, `image`.`updated_at` AS `updatedAt`, `keywords`.`id` AS `keywords.id`, 
`keywords`.`name` AS `keywords.name`, `keywords`.`created_at` AS `keywords.createdAt`, 
`keywords`.`updated_at` AS `keywords.updatedAt`, `keywords->image_keywords`.`id` AS 
`keywords.image_keywords.id`, `keywords->image_keywords`.`image_id` AS 
`keywords.image_keywords.image_id`, `keywords->image_keywords`.`keyword_id` AS 
`keywords.image_keywords.keyword_id`, `keywords->image_keywords`.`created_at` AS 
`keywords.image_keywords.createdAt`, `keywords->image_keywords`.`updated_at` AS 
`keywords.image_keywords.updatedAt` 

FROM `image` AS `image` INNER JOIN ( `image_keywords` AS `keywords->image_keywords` 
INNER JOIN `keywords` AS `keywords` 
ON `keywords`.`id` = `keywords->image_keywords`.`keyword_id`) 
ON `image`.`id` = `keywords->image_keywords`.`image_id` 
AND (`keywords`.`id` IN (430) AND `keywords`.`id` NOT IN (779));
```

I'm not clear if this is an issue with how I'm structuring the query, or a bug, or a complete misunderstanding on my part as to how this should work, but I'm really hoping for some guidance.

Comment: Why don't you use one array, treated before, to remove the ids in the 'inclause' which are in the 'outClause' ? The query will be more performant, no ?

Comment: There are images that will have only the wanted keywords, and images that have the wanted and unwanted keywords, and I’m trying to fetch the former and exclude the latter. I don’t know where the overlaps are until I query the images with the qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

Given the sample data below, are you expecting results ONLY image 1 (and NOT image 2)?

```
image id    keyword id
1           430
2           430
2           709
```

If so, then the problem is with your query. You would need to select **image id**s which have keyword id 709 and use that as the basis of your NOT IN statement.

Comment: That’s exactly what I’m trying to accomplish - yes. I see what you’re saying, I think, but I’m not sure how to structure that. Would I need to query twice, get the image ids for the exclusion keywords first, then pass that array into the second query? Can I accomplish that in one nested query? I’m brand new to the Sequelize syntax, so I’m not entirely clear the best way to structure this.

Comment: Accomplishing this in a single pass would require subqueries, which Sequelize doesn't really support.  You can simulate subqueries with [scopes](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/scopes.htmlscopes), but IMHO it would be awkward in this situation.
I would be tempted to embed a literal, something like:

`id:{
        Op.notIn: sequelize.literal('(SELECT image_id FROM image_keywords INNER JOIN keywords ON image_keywords.keyword_id = keywords.id WHERE keyword_id IN (?)')
   }`,

Comment: I’m using Node/Express - would it make sense if I chained promises and fetched the Images for the keywords to exclude and got an array of those image ids, then passed that array into a second fetch for the images I want and used the initial array as the Op.notIn parameter?

Comment: That should also work.  But, performance will likely decline a bit (2 trips to server), especially if your list of excluded images tends to be very large.